# Regex to match optional parameter

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regex to match an optional parameter at the end of a path.
I want to cover the first 4 paths but not the last one:

```
/main/sections/create-new
/main/sections/delete
/main/sections/
/main/sections
/main/sectionsextra
```

So far I've created this:

```
/\/main\/sections(\/)([a-zA-z]{1}[a-zA-z\-]{0,48}[a-zA-z]{1})?/g
```

This only finds the first 3. How can I make it match the first 4 cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may match the string in question up the optional string starting with `/` with any 1 or or more chars other than `/` after it up to the end of the string:

```
\/main\/sections(?:\/[^\/]*)?$
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bb2KYO/1). If you really need to constrain the optional subpart to only consist of just letters and `-` with the `-` not allowed at the start/end (with length of 2+ chars), use

```
/\/main\/sections(?:\/[a-z][a-z-]{0,48}[a-z])?$/i
```

Or, to also allow 1 char subpart:

```
/\/main\/sections(?:\/[a-z](?:[a-z-]{0,48}[a-z])?)?$/i
```

**Details**

- `\/main\/sections` - a literal substring `/main/sections`
- `(?:\/[^\/]*)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of:

  - `\/` - a `/` char
  - `[^\/]*` - a negated character class matching any 0+ chars other than `/`
- `$` - end of string.

JS demo:

```js
var strs = ['/main/sections/create-new','/main/sections/delete','/main/sections/','/main/sections','/main/sectionsextra'];
var rx = /\/main\/sections(?:\/[^\/]*)?$/;
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s, "=>", rx.test(s));
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works. there's just one problem about it, it also matches if the optional part is space separated.

Comment: @Reyraa Do you mean the last subpart cannot have whitespace? Just add `\s` to the negated character class, `[^\/]` => `[^\/\s]`. Also, forgot to add that [`[A-z]` matches more than just letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926). I added some more variations to show how far you may go here with the restrictions.